# Get batch by batch about 70K of data

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I need to get about 70.000 lines from database and I want to get batch by batch but like I did I get only some lines :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ".self::TABLE_NAME;
    $stmt = Db::get()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetch();
    $batches = $results['num'] / 1000;
    $limit = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $batches; $i++) {
        $offset = $i * 1000;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".self::TABLE_NAME." LIMIT $limit,$offset";
        $stmt = Db::get()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo $result['supplierName'].PHP_EOL;
        }
        $limit+=1000;
    }
```

Have you an idea ? Thx in advance.

Comment: Why are you changing `$limit`? And what happens if you don't have a total number of records perfectly divisible by 1000? And isn't the syntax `LIMIT _offset, limit_`?

Comment: @Jonnix Probably because it starts at `0` in `$limit = 0;` and they were not paying attention

Comment: @RiggsFolly But it increases by 1000 on every iteration of the outer for

Comment: @Jonnix Yea, thats wrong I agree, but thats probably because they started it at `0` and were not paying attention

Comment: ___Small Point___ There is not much point preparing a query if you have already concatenated all the values into it and do not have any parameters to bind !!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I gotcha, first bit of my original comment was a bit vague.

Comment: @Jonnix No first comment was perfect. I also spotted that and then your comment and just thought i would throw my hat in the ring :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly You're always welcome to ;)

Comment: You also have no code to work out when you have processed all your row data

Comment: can you provide some small pieces of code please ?  @Jonnix

Comment: Change `$limit = 0;` to `$limit = 1000;` and remove the line `$limit+=1000;` LIMIT is the number of rows you want returned so it should not change, OFFSET is where you want to start collecting rows from, so that should change

Comment: It would also be useful to add a `ORDER BY` to your query so you are sure you are using the exaclt same resultset on each iteration of the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have 11 rows in database, but the query generated is : `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1000,0` and no rows for this condition

Comment: Oh missed this bit :) change `LIMIT $limit,$offset` to `LIMIT $offset, $limit`